# Cannot install ruby-debug gem on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, ruby-debug

I'm having trouble installing the Ruby-Debug Gem on windows. What does this error mean? How can I fix this? Thanks

```
C:\Users\Steve>gem install ruby-debug
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing ruby-debug:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/Ruby19/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more
details. You may need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/Ruby19/bin/ruby
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache-
0.43 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache-0.43/ext/gem_make
.out
```

I have the following Gems:

```
actionpack (2.3.5, 2.3.3)
activerecord (2.3.5, 2.3.3)
activeresource (2.3.5, 2.3.3)
activesupport (2.3.5, 2.3.3)
columnize (0.3.1)
json_pure (1.2.0)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5, 2.3.3)
rake (0.8.7)
rmagick (1.14.1)
rubyforge (2.0.3)
rubygems-update (1.3.5)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5) 
with rails version 3.3.5
```

Comment: It means it doesn't work with Ruby 1.9 yet.

Comment: You already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972549/

Answer (score 19):

Execute Below command and its works

C:\Users\Steve>gem install ruby-debug --platform=mswin32

Comment: I tried this but when I try to run my server in debug mode it says it can't find `ruby-debug-base`, even though it's on my gems list and listed in my Gemfile. Any ideas?

Comment: The same, it installed correctly but `Could not find ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.4.0) amongst...` when executing `rdebug rake`

Comment: paste here complete error stack, I will try to help to fix that problem

Comment: Comments don't allow that many characters.
rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.4.0) [... ruby-debug-base-0.10.4-x86-mswin32, ...] (Gem::LoadError)
 from .../rubygems/specification.rb:777:in `block in activate_dependencies'
 from .../rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
 from .../rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
 from .../rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
 from C:/Ruby193/bin/rdebug:22:in `<main>'

Comment: Do you have installed ruby-debug-base window version?

Comment: I too am getting the `Could not find ruby-debug-base` error.  See [here](http://pastebin.com/nBM3LaJE) for the complete error.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem. Following steps should get you through:

1. Install ruby using [**RubyInstaller**](http://rubyinstaller.org/)
2. Install [**devkit**](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/development-kit)
3. Install **ruby-debug19** instead of **ruby-debug**.

   gem install ruby-debug19

Comment: @Palani, the question was specific to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Run: gem install **ruby-debug19**

[More info...](http://wiki.github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug/installation-command-line-version)

Answer (score 2):

this  [port of ruby-debug that works on 1.9.2 and 1.9.3](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger#readme) worked for me. Just type

```
gem install debugger
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer worked easiest for me:
http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit

Answer (score 1):

The error seems clear:

```
Can't handle 1.9.x yet

*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

You're trying to install ruby-debug gem, which is compatible **only**
with Ruby 1.8.x on Ruby 1.9.x

Please install ruby-debug19, which is compatible with Ruby 1.9.x

```
gem install ruby-debug19
```

Comment: ruby-debug19 needs some headers and those headers are not available along with 1.9.2

Comment: Palani Kannan: your comment is not accurate. ruby-debug19 gems requires Ruby source code which will be downloaded during the gem installation.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this:

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre
```